# Pass width and height of canvas to constructor of class

Tags: java, android

I need to pass the value of the canvas width and height to the constructor of the a `Player` class when I create that object in the constructor of the `GameSurfaceView` class below. The problem is that I can't get hold of any value of the canvas width and height at that time. The only way, so far for me, is that I can get the width and height of the canvas inside the `Run()` method, but then it's to late because the object I already cretated.

I came up with and idea to pass a reference of the `GameSurfaceView` to a second constructor of the `Player` class, so I could pass and get the value that way from the canvas, but I guess, there will be no value at that moment either, when the object is created!

Please, ask if my question is unclear. Below is the main part of the code I'm using. I'm also using a `MainActivity` class to create an object of the class below.

```
public class GameSurfaceView extends SurfaceView implements Runnable {
    SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
    Canvas canvas;
    int screenWidth, screenHeight;

    // Constructor
    public GameSurfaceView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        surfaceHolder = getHolder();

        // Create player sprite object
        player = new Player(texturePlayer, xPlayer, yPlayer);       
    }

    // Create player sprite object alternative 2
    player = new Player(this, texturePlayer, xPlayer, yPlayer);     
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();

        screenWidth = canvas.getWidth();
        screenHeight = canvas.getHeight();

        // Do the drawing to screen here
        surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);  
    }
}
```